# Choose which debugged process to "Take Snapshot" of

Tags: visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

I'm debugging a test of NamedPipes, so I am debugging both a client and server project running in a single solution using:

> right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer > Set StartUp Projects...

I'd like to view the difference in heap usage of my Server application, but the Diagnostic Tools "Take Snapshot" seems to just get the details of the Client application.

**Is there a place I'm missing that allows me to choose which process the Diagnostic Tools are following?**

Comment: I guessed it was choosing the alphabetically first startup project name, or the first project GUID, but changing both of those didn't produce a useful workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using the first StartUp project listed in the Solution Properties dialogue box that is displayed by the right-click > Set StartUp Projects..., and there's up and down arrows there to change the ordering.